# How to pass props to React Big Calendar from custom event?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, custom-events, react-big-calendar

I need your help.
I have a custom event in react big calendar who has a button inside. When I click the button, I want to pass a value to calendar component.

I have no clue how to do that. Can you help me? Thanks!

```
export const Schedule = (params) => {
 const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
 const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValue("aaa");
  };
return (
  <Calendar
    components={{event.CustomEvent}}
    eventPropGetter={(event) => ({
       style: {
         borderLeft: "5px solid",
         display: "block",
       },
    })}
    events={events}
  />
)
}
```

And the EventComponent

```
const EventComponent = (props) => {
  const BtnChangeValue = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick = {setValue("this should change value from Calendar")}></button
      </>
    );
  };

 return(
   <>
     <div>aaaaaa</div>
     <BtnChangeValue onClick={????} />
     <div>eeeee</div>
   </>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `components` props to this:

```
components={{event: () => <CustomEvent onClick={onClickHandler}/>}}
```

In your EventComponent, pass the props `onClick` like this:

```
const EventComponent = (props) => {
  const BtnChangeValue = ({ ...args }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <button {...args}></button
      </>
    );
  };

 return(
   <>
     <div>aaaaaa</div>
     <BtnChangeValue onClick={props.onClick} />
     <div>eeeee</div>
   </>
 )
}
```

Comment: Great, works like a charm. One more question: If I want to use the event Name and other properties from event, how should I do?
LIKE:

```
<div>{event.name}</div>
     <BtnChangeValue onClick={props.onClick} />
     <div>{event.id}</div>
```

Comment: Assuming that you will pass all properties via props in ```CustomEvent``` then you can access them using ```props.name``` and so on